# Reflection is quad dependent and looks non realistic

Tags: rendering

Im rendering varous objects with a Sharp glossy effect but the reflections are quad dependent on the object *(image below)*, meaning they **behave separately** within every quad making it look 8bit-like. Can anyone tell me why this happens?. (Im pretty sure subdividing would fix it but I want to know why I cant have a low poly object reflecting normaly.

The object has 2 modifiers: Subdiv Surface and Solidify. (Perhaps the Subdiv is causing it?). Help me you Blender savys I dont have a powerful CPU to test and test within every render would take me hours and hours.

Image:

[image: Quad dependent reflections.]

Comment: Do objects have [smooth shading](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/smoothing.html) ?

Comment: @KhrisAzuaje if smooth shading doesn't fix the issue please upload the .blend file and edit your question to add the link.

Comment: My problem was fixed making normals consist and fixing a few errors on the mesh (2 extrudes on the same place).
Smoothing seems to be working perfectly fine after that!. Thanks guys I'll select smoothing as the right answer.

Comment: @KhrisAzuaje it would be more useful if you write the answer detailing what you did. If you can add pictures showing the before and after of the issues you were dealing with it would a be better learning experience for others down the line.

Comment: It all worked together with the Smoothing, after fixing my mesh it still looked odd and it was just perfect with the smoothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Mr Zak pointed out you need to use smooth shading to get cleaner reflections on a glossy material.

[image]

The following example should make it clear, both of the spheres are identical, and have the same amount of subdivision (2) on the subsurf modifier

[image]

Comment: I'll select this as the right answer, could you add a tip of making normals consist and checking if the meshe's geometry has errors, it can be a problem for reflections (2 vertex, edges or faces on the same place, etc).
For future reference of people having problems with reflections