# Cubic Shading in Blender Internal

Tags: shaders, lighting, error

While I was modelling this model in blender, once I got to the arms I noticed that in render the shading on the arms and lower body was cubic. I'm not sure if this is a lighting issue or a polygon issue, and I don't know how to fix it.

The Suns are set to raytrace. The issue doesn't occur with 1000 x 1000 renders, and can't upload an image due to it being over 2MB.
[image]

This one doesn't have any problems.

[image]

This one does.

Comment: Could you crop the image, and upload a part of it where the problem is visible? Also, reducing to 256 colours and saving as PNG with high compression often reduces the size considerably, but colour decimation may of course introduce artifacts or hide artifacts that are clearly visible with a larger range of colours.

Comment: Are you using smooth shading and usbsurf modifiers?

Comment: Yes, the subsurf modifier is set to 2 for rendering

Comment: related?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36274/reflection-is-quad-dependent-and-looks-non-realistic/36280#36280

Comment: Yes, and applied to all of the objects.

Comment: Maybe you should try spotlamp with buffer shadow

Comment: That seemed to work.